# A silly confusion related to order of identity element in a group.

Tags: group-theory

I am asked to prove or disprove that $|a| =|b|$ if $|a^2|=|b^2|$ in a group $G$, where $|x|$ denotes order of element $x$ in $G$.

Somewhere when I read that Klein's four group disproves the statement $|a|= |b|$. 
Clearly Klein's four group is a group having every element as self invertible. Order of every non-identity element is $2$. Can we take $a$ as any non-identity element of this group and $b$ as identity of the group?

I am not getting how this group will disprove the statement as order of identity is always $1$ (if I  am not wrong).

Also help me to prove or disprove this if this group doesn't works here.

Comment: A simpler example is the (cyclic) group with $2$ elements, but any group containing an element of even order (and thus an element of order $2$) will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you take $a$ to be any non-identity element of the Klein $4$-group and $b$ to be the identity, you have $|a^2|=|b^2|=|b|=1$, but $|a|=2\ne 1=|b|$. This shows that $|a^2|=|b^2|$ does not imply that $|a|=|b|$.